# How to display camel rest parameter List of Objects with Swagger

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, swagger

How can one have **camel-swagger-java** scan a camel rest api route and represent a rest endpoint parameter that is a list of pojo objects where those pojos have json properties?

When attempting to use List or SamplePojo[] as the camel rest endpoint body, both `.type(SamplePojo[].class)` and `.typeList(SamplePojo.class)` are used by camel-swagger-java to produce an api page that shows the body just being a string instead of showing json for all the properties in the SamplePojo class.

There is an .arrayType method that can be used on route parameters, but there isn't mention of what should be specified:  .arrayType("whatHere?")

Attempts using it below have swagger showing the type as just a string, not the json properties:

`.arrayType(SamplePojo.class.getName())`

*RestOperationParamDefinition*:

```
/**
 * Sets the Swagger Parameter array type.
 * Required if data type is "array". Describes the type of items in the array.
 */
public void setArrayType(String arrayType) {
    this.arrayType = arrayType;
}
```

Someone asked this without a resolution:

https://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/How-to-get-long-and-array-data-types-working-in-camel-swagger-java-td5775343.html

There are camel examples for swagger, but not with a List param example:

https://github.com/Talend/apache-camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-swagger-cdi/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/example/cdi/UserRouteBuilder.java

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: 2.21.0.fuse-760027-redhat-00001

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. As I can figure out this setter support only simple types (string, float etc). Below sources from org.apache.camel.swagger.RestSwaggerReader:

```
if (isArray) {
if (param.getArrayType() != null) {
    if (param.getArrayType().equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {
        defineItems(serializableParameter, allowableValues, new StringProperty(), String.class);
    }
    if (param.getArrayType().equalsIgnoreCase("int")
            || param.getArrayType().equalsIgnoreCase("integer")) {
        defineItems(serializableParameter, allowableValues, new IntegerProperty(),
                Integer.class);
    }
    if (param.getArrayType().equalsIgnoreCase("long")) {
        defineItems(serializableParameter, allowableValues, new LongProperty(), Long.class);
    }
    if (param.getArrayType().equalsIgnoreCase("float")) {
        defineItems(serializableParameter, allowableValues, new FloatProperty(), Float.class);
    }
    if (param.getArrayType().equalsIgnoreCase("double")) {
        defineItems(serializableParameter, allowableValues, new DoubleProperty(), Double.class);
    }
    if (param.getArrayType().equalsIgnoreCase("boolean")) {
        defineItems(serializableParameter, allowableValues, new BooleanProperty(),
                Boolean.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it to string first and then use JacksonDataFormat by specifying Pojo class.

`.convertBodyTo(String.class).unmarshal(new JacksonDataFormat(Pojo[].class))`